# Xamarin Application Not Updating (Visual Studio)

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

Whenever I make a change to the front end of my visual studio xamarin application it dosn't update on the application ran on the emulator. Furthermore the changes on the front end are not saved when close down the project and start it again.

So my .cs(backend) file changes are being saved but the .axml(Frontend) changes are not.

- Visual Studio Version: Latest (Free Adition)
- Android: 8.1(Oreo)
- Xamarin: Latest

Comment: You must run a deploy in order to see the changes in the application. Some time by running only a build the changes are not reflected to the application. After the new deployment, app will be uninstalled from the emulator and installed again.

Comment: I've uninstalled the application from the emulator and re-installed on a build, the app still isn't showing the updated front-end.

Answer (score 0):

Would propose deleting `bin` and `obj` folders, then clean and rebuild the solution. At the same time close the simulator to start a new deploy.

Can't image why "the changes on the front end are not saved when close down the project" though.. Looks like if you where saving to a remote location where files are not saved and you have changes only kept in memory.

Comment: I have deleted the contents of those folders, and when I try to clean the application, it says the clean failed, but the re-build worked. Can I see why the clean has failed? Also the changes are still not showing after I re-deployed it.

Comment: haha, this destroys most of my application (and I'm a student) so now I have to check a lot to see why is failing too. My mac send those two folders to trash and rename them because they were same name, now I don't know which one is the correct one.

Comment: you dont need bin and obj subfolders inside the project, they are autogenerated by ide and upon build.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I fixed it by deleting and recreating the Android emulator

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32297566)